# Synchronized pulse generation from wirelessly connected boards

Tags: wireless, time

I want two or more boards (less than 10m range) to generate a LED blink at same time, within 1 ms difference, using wireless communication. First, due to power consumption, I am thinking to use bluetooth low energy as wireless medium. My concept is basic: each board has a microcontroller and a bluetooth module. One of the board will just broadcast a signal every minute and also blink a LED. The receiver will blink LED based on the set time interval, and whenever it gets signal from the broadcaster it will blink. Thus the outputs are synchronized every minute.

I would like to know how feasible this concept is or if I am overlooking something, because it looks pretty simple design. Or any other alternative solutions? Board size, power consumption and time synchronization are main constraints here.

Comment: Are you sure you need radio communication? If the boards won't move IR communication is probably way to go. 10m is quite a lot but maybe you are outdoor. Using an IR solution would save an incredible amount of power. Anyway let me get this right: you want a blink every minute with a max error of 1ms is this correct? The period will never change?

Comment: @VladimirCravero The boards will not be always in line of sight, so I can't use IR. Yes, the boards should blink at same time (error < 1 ms). The frequency of blinking will be set once when programming the MCU.

Comment: Line of sight is not always necessary for IR communication. Ever tried to fire your remote pointing backwards? Anyway I think I am getting it: you would have a somewhat higer frequency and the every-minute broadcast would just be there to sync the units, right?

Comment: @VladimirCravero Yes, the broadcast is just to sync the units

Answer (score 2):

This is probably overkill, but since GPS modules are cheap, you could simply put one on each of your PCBs. The 1-pps output of modules that have them are generally synced to within something on the order of 50-100 ns, but even if you only have access to the serial output, 1 ms should be easy to achieve.

Comment: I guess the main problem would be higher power, bigger size and weak indoor signal.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be alright with that specification but just to cancel out as many errors as possible why don't you engineer it along the lines of one transmitter that feeds two receivers. It doesn't have to be physically implemented this way because the synchronizing transmitter can be placed on the same PCB as one of the receivers.

If you do it this way then you are processing the radio sync signal identically rather than the transmitter trying to estimate how long it will take the receiver to decode the radio message.

Comment: I was thinking that a couple of very precise quartz is the way to go, iff the units are always on. He just need to sync them once on startup, maybe with a twi and he's good to go. T compensated quartz is cheap enough, cheaper than a radio sistem both in $$ and W.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: Do the math: Even a 1 ppm crystal (not cheap!) will be off by more than 1 ms within 1000 seconds (16 minutes). This is probably not good enough for the required run time of the application.

Comment: @DaveTweed that's right, my fault. I've read of a problem some guys had with a sort of portable missile shield that stopped working if was kept on too much time but that was probably referring to a difference in time... They solved it with a firmware upgrade so I thought that could be easy. ofc it was military equipment so they maybe had some better time reference on board.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know blue tooth.  But there are a number of RC (radio control) IC's that do Tx and Rx. (27 MHz is/was popular.)  You'd have to look into the details, but timing to 1ms should not be too hard.  (I was interested in this years ago, so I don't know what's available now... maybe someone else has a suggestion for a Tx/Rx pair.)